# Do transmission drive gears slide onto a keyed/splined shaft for manual transmissions, or is the entire piece one unit?

Tags: transmission, gear-ratio

So this is obviously a "one size fits most" question, and my actual real world use case may not represent the answers I get here, but I'm curious. I'm looking at doing an electric motor swap into a ford probe, which has a [mazda g5m transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_G5M_transmission). I'd be using a Nissan Leaf which has a 8.2 drive ratio in it's gearbox (which I would not be using). The stock probe gear ratios are (with final drive) 13.56 / 7.52 / 5.06 / 3.75 / 2.94. From my understanding the first gear would be great for burning up my tires, but not so great for actually driving. This is fine -- the leaf only needs one gear, having 4 would be incredible luxury.

That said -- I'm curious as an academic question really. If I look at some other vehicles that use the g5m transmission, they have gear ratios not available in the stock probe. If the shafts in the transmission are single pieces of milled metal obviously it wouldn't be possible to swap around individual gear ratios, but if they were keyed or splined I might be able to redefine what gear is what, like if I could grab a transmission out of a 2.0 probe I could shift everything up 1 gear and add a 2.93 ratio as my tallest gear.

This is of course hypothetical -- mainly just wondering along the lines of "is this possible?".

TL;DR -- Could I just move cogs up and down a keyed shaft to change which gear is which ratio, or is the entire shaft/cog assembly a single milled piece of metal?

Comment: For the inevitable "If you don't know this simple thing how are you going to electric swap a vehicle", the answer is this will be a passion project, not my daily driver. It can set in the garage for months on end while I figure things out and explore.

Comment: I don't get the remark *"the leaf only needs one gear, having 4 would be incredible luxury."* A gearbox isn't a luxury, but a necessity when the torque curve is not flat. That's what an electric motor gives, and having more than one gear wouldn't be a luxury, but over-engineering.

Comment: ... it's the crucial range below about 3000 rpm where an ICE needs a gearbox to be able to operate at efficient engine rpm. Above that their typical performance decays about the same. Please see [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Torque-Curves-of-Electric-Motor-and-Internal-Combustion-Engine-2-The-electric-motors-can_fig5_370553199). *...electric motors can give maximum torque from 0 rpm and can maintain this maximum torque in a wide rpm range*. So if you want to keep the original transmission in your project, just stay in top gear.